# How to customize Outlook contact TAPI call form though code

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, tapi

I want to customize existing TAPI outlook contact call dialogue form through code, when i selected call from business it display the new call dialogue box and I want to customize that form.

Comment: Where art *though* code?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, from outlook contact item when we right click contact item we can see the call menu, when we select any call menu item, the TAPI call dialogue box opens with the contact item name and phone number and start call button is their to start the call in the TAPI dialogue box. I want to customize the existing TAPI dialogue box using C# code. Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: Then is their any solution to achieve this through code. i want to customize existing windows TAPI exe file. thanks.